# Calibration of SVM Probability

Tags: r, probability, svm, calibration

I am using 2-class SVM from `e1071` R-Package. 
I have been recommended to calibrate the output of classifier.
In this regard, I found this [page](http://danielnee.com/tag/platt-scaling/). The code works for me and I want to apply it in my project; however, I am not sure about the vector of `pred` which its definition is "vector of predictions of each observation from the classifier. Should be real number."

The output of my classifier is like this:

```
    Decision values:
t34a t34b 
   0    0 
attr(,"decision.values")
            1/0
t34a -0.2859799
t34b -0.4527416
attr(,"probabilities")
              1         0
t34a 0.17057557 0.8294244
t34b 0.07377427 0.9262257
Levels: 0 1
```

Do you know I should use which of this information for `pred`? decision values? or probability values of target class, say class 1, i.e. first column of probability values?

Also, do you know how I should apply it in learning procedure?
Typically, the learning procedure is as follows:

1) estimation of performance of SVM using Leave-One-Out cross-validation.

2) training SVM with whole training samples,

3) and then evaluating the model by testing samples.

If I want to use calibration technique, where I can do that?

I appreciated if you could help me.